# How could I "adjust" (in authomatic way) the way in which a reference to an appendix result appears? Could that be customized? (A.1 vs 1)

Tags: hyperref, labels, appendices, ref, newtheorem

In the following lines of code (a MWE), I intend to have appendix results named like A.1, A.2, etc. (see line "\newtheorem{APP.}{A.}").

> ```
> \documentclass[12pt,oneside,english]{report} 
>
> \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
> \geometry{verbose, tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm, headsep=0.5cm, footskip=1cm}
> \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
> \newtheorem{APP.}{A.}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \tableofcontents
>   
> \chapter{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}\label{chap: Brownian motion theory}
> \justify 
> \pagenumbering{arabic}
> \lhead{\textbf{\rightmark}}
> \section{WWWWWW}\label{subsec: History of Brownian motion}
> \justify 
> As pointed out in \ref{app.:law XXXXXX}...
>
>
> \chapter{Appendix} \label{app: Appendix ACCA}
> \begin{APP.}\textbf{(Law XXXXXX)}\label{app.:law XXXXXX}
> \noindent According to ...
>
> \end{APP.}
>     
> \end{document}
> ```

Appendix part will appear as:

[image]

Hence, as intended, first appendix result will be named A.1.

---

---

With the line:

> ```
>  As pointed out in \ref{app.:law XXXXXX}...
> ```

I get the output:

> As pointed out in 1

While I would like to get instead:

> As pointed out in A.1

---

---

---

I understand the point and the reason of that. Is there any possible **authomatic** way (I know how to do it manually, but it is too time-expensive) to get A.1 instead of 1 in the body text reference? Should I make some adjustment as to the way in which I define the appendix (which currently corresponds to "\newtheorem{APP.}{A.}") or should I make any adjustment somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I process your MWE with `pdflatex` there are several problems including "undefined control sequence" and a `hyperref` problem.

In the code below I have commented out the problematic lines.

```
% newtheoremprob.tex  SE 568951

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,english]{report} 

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm, headsep=0.5cm, footskip=1cm}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % PW causes a problem
%%    \newtheorem{APP.}{A.}[chapter]
\newtheorem{APP.}{}[chapter] % changed by PW

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
  
\chapter{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}\label{chap: Brownian motion theory}
%%%    \justify % PW undefined control sequence
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%    \lhead{\textbf{\rightmark}} % PW undefined control sequence
\section{WWWWWW}\label{subsec: History of Brownian motion}
%%%    \justify % PW undefined control sequence
As pointed out in \ref{app.:law XXXXXX}...

\appendix  % added by PW
\chapter{Appendix} \label{app: Appendix ACCA}
\begin{APP.}\textbf{(Law XXXXXX)}\label{app.:law XXXXXX}
\noindent According to ...

\end{APP.}
    
\end{document}
```

I didn't like your **Chapter 2 Appendix** and changed that because an Appendix is not a chapter, although an appendix include one or more chapters. I also changed your `\newtheorem` specification. Now you get the reference style you are after.